# anchor tag inside ul before li

Tags: html

I am adding an anchor tag inside ul and inside anchor tag I am adding li. But when I tested this on html validator it gives me error. Is there a proper way to achieve this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
<a href="#"><li>Click one</li></a>
<a href="#"><li>Click one</li></a>
<a href="#"><li>Click one</li></a>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 25):

Convert it to these:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Click one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Click one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Click one</a></li>
</ul>
```

Because `li` should always have a parent of `ul`, that is the cause of your error. But I think you wanted your whole `li` to be clickable so this CSS style will fix it.

```
ul li a { display:block; }
```

That will display it.

Answer (score 3):

This question is very old but I want to add something to it:

This CSS should also force the anchor element be the same width and height of the parent li which would achieve the desired effect as well.

```
ul li a {
    width:inherit;
    height:inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The whole `li` will be clickable if you style up the `li a`, like this:

```css
ul li a {
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be putting `<li>` tags outside the `<a>` tags not the other way round.

Comment: I know I should but I want that whole li element should be clickable. How can I make it clickable by putting li outside?